# PHP MySQL Query not working

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a form made in js by my developer, and I have implemented a function where I am sent an email, and the input data from the form is put into a mysql query and then into my database. However the database query doesn't work in the method, neither does any echos or anything. By this I mean that the query is not run, and no echos show up on the page containing this code.

Please can you tell me what is causing this?

Here is the process() method where the error is occuring:

```
    function process()
    {
       echo "hi";
        $device = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Device_Type']);
        $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Name']);
        $job = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['DD']);
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Username']);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Email']);
        $website = $_POST['Website']);
        $UDID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['UDID']);
        mysql_connect("localhost", "...", "...");
        mysql_select_db("...");
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO Beta_Testers (`Name`, `Username`, `Email Address`, `Website`, `Job`, `Device_Type`, `UDID`) VALUES ('$name','$username','$email','$website','$job','$device','$UDID')") or die(mysql_error());   
          $msg = "Form Contents: \n\n";
          foreach($this->fields as $key => $field)
                $msg .= "$key :  $field \n ";
          $to = '';
          $subject = 'Beta Form Submission';
          $from = 'Beta Sign up';
          mail($to, $subject, $msg, "From: $from\r\nReply-To: $from\r\nReturn-Path: $from\r\n");   
       }
```

Comment: Question too broad and vague. No details given about the error message, only a ton-o-code which apparently `doesn't work`.

Comment: You say no `echo` occurs... considering the `echo` is the first line of the function, are you sure you're even calling it?

Comment: and BTW, I can inject SQL in that query ;)

Comment: Yes I am as the emails are going through.

Comment: @AlexanderMP, what do I need to do to prevent this?!

Comment: either use mysql_real_escape_string for each and every parameter (you missed $website), or use PDO, or other means of working automatically with parametrized queries.

Comment: Maybe you should talk to your developer. Although I hesitate to call him/her a "developer" looking at this POS. No offence.

Comment: Haha, I think that you are right. It seems that the method actually isn't being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the line with `$website`. You have an extra parenthesis on the end (or perhaps, a missing `mysql_real_escape` call on the other side).

To check for syntax errors like this in the future, run `php -l myfile.php` on the command line. Or, during development and testing, make sure you have [`error_reporting`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) and [`display_errors`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) configured correctly so that these syntax errors are displayed in the script's output.